# Como importar um grande arquivo .txt com data.frames e colunas?

Tags: r, datatable, big-data

Olá, tudo bem ?

Preciso **importar** um db grande que está em **.txt e dividido em 20 partes de 5Gb** cada (aproximadamente).

Dentro dessa base **existem três data.frame, com 3 quantidades de colunas diferentes.**

As **colunas são separadas por espaços fixos.**

Estou tentando usar `data.table()` e `read_fwf()`,  mas estou tendo problemas em separar as colunas devido aos três data.frames diferentes.

A coluna "TIPO DE REGISTRO" identifica os data.frames.

A base é essa (o layout esta aqui também):

http://receita.economia.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/cadastros/cadastro-nacional-de-pessoas-juridicas-cnpj/dados-publicos-cnpj

Alguém tem alguma dica? 
Desde já, muito obrigado !

---

ps¹: Tentei usar: `devtools::install_github("georgevbsantiago/qsacnpj")` com

```
    qsacnpj::gerar_bd_cnpj(path_arquivos_txt = "C:/Users/Downloads/",
                           localizar_cnpj = "NAO",
                           n_lines = 10000,
                           armazenar = "csv")
```

Mas demora muito ! Quando tentei n_lines = 100000, o computador travou no sexto arquivo.

ps²: meu computador não tem tanta memória.

Comment: Você tem certeza que não se trata de uma limitação de memória RAM disponível?

Comment: Sobre a demora, eu acho que é justamente isso ! Gostaria de dicas para driblar esse problema. Por isso tentei o data.table(), mas não estou sabendo lidar.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos quando eu digo que existem três data.frame nessa base, eles estão "misturados". Por isso a dificuldade em separar.

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu computador não tem memória RAM o suficiente para carregar esses dados, eu os carregaria em um [SGDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) como o [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) (mesmo sendo fwf) e puxaria os dados a partir do R utilizando [algum pacote](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/postgresql/) para interagir com o PostgreSQL. Desse modo, você tem os dados carregados na sua máquina e pode puxar *subsets* desses dados para analisá-los com o R.

Na pior das hipóteses, você pode fazer suas análises em *subsets* desses dados e fazer um *summary* ao final para consolidar para o *dataset* por completo. Além disso, claro, você pode fazer várias operações direto nos dados do banco através de [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso ! Obrigado !